# Typescript error while array filtered on type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of `number | undefined`s and I want the max of this array, if any of them is a number. In order to do so I want to filter on the element being of type number, so that I can pass a numbers-only array to `Math.max(...array)`

(I know I shouldn't Math.max on an desctructured empty array, so I'll only do a math.max if there are 1 or more numeric values in the array)

```js
const numbersArray: number[] = [a,b].filter((v) => typeof v === "number");
```

That works fine in runtime, but I get a typescript error saying that I cant assert `numbersArray` to be of type number[].

```
Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you need something liek this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDArmAJgUwGYEsyboCwAUKJLAEZIwCMp50MYKAtpZgE4QCCnncAJ4AuZmw6cA2gF0akuABpK0gHR4ANlC4AKbQDdRLdlxgAfVBhz5CASlGUQIdZjhgkAPhh6YAQkTI0LDwCdBt4CDFjKWkAbiA ?

Comment: Having to cast `as number[]` makes no sense to me. That's forcing TS to do what it doesn't do naturally, but naturally the `filter` fn returns a number array so why is it complaining... so confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately typescript doesn't understand `filter` for some reason.

The usual solution would be to do a typecast

```
const numbersArray: number[] = [1, undefined, 3].filter((v): v is number => typeof v === "number");
```

However for some reason typescript understands `flatMap` so you can use that  as an alternative. Just beware that IE doesn't support it natively so it needs to be transplied if you're aiming to support it.

```
const numbersArray: number[] = [1, undefined, 3].flatMap(v => typeof v === "number" ? [v] : []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce method:

```
const myArray: number|undefined[] = []

let filteredArray: number[]  = []
filteredArray = myArray.reduce<number[]>((previous, current) => current ? [...previous, current] : previous, [])
```